# ¿Cómo obtener los siguientes elementos de un XML con Linq?

Tags: c#, .net

necesito obtener algunos elementos del siguiente XML

```
<AccessControlPolicy xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Owner>
    <ID>eb47c9ec-1f6f-4eab-b5c8-ae3ca3033ad1</ID>
  </Owner>
  <AccessControlList>
    <Grant>
      <Grantee xsi:type="CanonicalUser" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ID>eb47c9ec-1f6f-4eab-b5c8-ae3ca3033ad1</ID>
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
    </Grant>
    <Grant>
      <Grantee xsi:type="Group" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <URI>http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers</URI>
      </Grantee>
      <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
    </Grant>
  </AccessControlList>
</AccessControlPolicy>
```

Particularmente necesito obtener los valores de Permission, ID y y los valores de los atributos xsi:type. Estoy trabajando con Linq (así lo exige el desarrollo).

¿Alguna idea de como obtener los elementos?

Lo hecho hasta ahora:

```
        //Obtengo los nodos Grant del xml
        XElement element = Xml.FirstNode as XElement;

        List<XElement> elementosEncontrados = new List<XElement>();
        foreach (XElement ele in element.Descendants())
        {
            if (ele.Name.LocalName == "AccessControlList")
            {
                foreach (XElement entryData in ele.Descendants().Where(X => X.Name.LocalName == "Grant"))
                {
                    elementosEncontrados.Add(ele);
                }

            }
        }

        //Obtengo las propiedades (ID, Permission)
        int iId = 0;
        int iPer = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> propiedades = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (XElement elem in elementosEncontrados[0].Descendants())
        {
            if (elem.Name.LocalName == "ID")
            {
                propiedades.Add("ID" + iId, elem.Value);
                iId++;
            }

            if (elem.Name.LocalName == "Permission")
            {
                propiedades.Add("Permission" + iPer, elem.Value);
                iPer++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Probaste con Linq to XML?

Comment: Sí, pero solo pude obtener los valores de las etiquetas Permission y ID. No tengo la menor idea de como obtener el valor de la propiedad xsi:type de la etiqueta Grantee.

Comment: Si agregas lo que intentaste hasta ahora, podremos empezar por ahi y ayudarte con lo que falta

Comment: Listo, he añadido el código que he desarrollado hasta ahora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estuve revisando tu codigo.

Veo una cosa que podes mejorar seguro, probablemente leer id y permission tambien se puedan mejorar.

La lista de elementos de grant, se puede obtener directamente sin tener quer recorrer todo el xml de la siguiente forma:

```
List<XElement> listagrant = element
    .Descendants()
    .Where(X => X.Name.LocalName == "Grant")
    .ToList();
```

Si quisieras que fuera solo para los nodos de AccessControlList, solo deberias agregar un where mas arriba.

Para obtener los atributos que estas buscando, podes hacer algo asi:

```
List<XAttribute> listatributos = new List<XAttribute>();
//obtener la declaracion del namespace
var uri = listagrant
    .First()
    .Descendants()
    .First()
    .Attributes()
    .Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
    .First();
XNamespace aw = uri.Value;
foreach (XElement x in listagrant)
{
    var y = x
        .Descendants()
        .Attributes()
        .Where(p => p.Name ==  aw+"type")
        .ToList();
    listatributos.AddRange(y);
}
```

Fijate que tuve que buscar y crear el nombre del namespace del documento, porque eso era lo que te estaba molestando a la hora de buscar tus nodos.

Comment: En efecto, apenas estoy iniciando con las consultas (jamás las había usado) y sí, el namespace del documento es lo que no me permitía obtener el valor xsi:Type. Con una ligera modificación puedo llenar una instancia con estos elementos para poder manipularlos. Tu respuesta fue de inmensa ayuda para mi. Muchas gracias :)